# C strcpy( ) does not cut char character

Tags: c++, strcpy

I am surprised, after writing and running following C++ code below on Red Hat Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char natureofGoods[17];
 char *name="sadasdasdasdas171212";

 strcpy(natureofGoods,name);

 cout<<natureofGoods<<endl;
}
```

I would wait here as output "sadasdasdasdas17" because `natureofGoods` has 17 characters size. But I took as output whole string. I mean  "sadasdasdasdas171212asdadsfsf"
If I run this code on Visual Studio, then my program crashes with a Debug Message as I am waiting. Why does not `strcpy` cut from 17. Character of name and afterwards copy into `natureofGoods`?

How can `natureofGoods` storage more caracter than its size?

Comment: Take a look at strncpy.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you are not using a `std::string`?

Comment: @SBI - and make sure you understand it before you use it. Every use of `strncpy` that I've seen on SO has been wrong, replacing undefined behavior with data corruption. Even if you use it right, it doesn't gain much: with `strcpy` you have to check that the string you're copying is short enough to fit; with `strncpy` you have to check that the copy succeeded.

Comment: I managed to miss the ++ in the tag... I should be taking a nap.

Answer (score 10):

`strcpy` attempts to copy characters from the source until it reaches a null-terminator - `'\0'`. You're breaking this contract because `natureofGoods` isn't big enough and so run into undefined behavior.

**Use `std::string`!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: Great answer (as always from @Luchian Grigore and an axiomatic +1), but do consider the overhead of using `std::string`.

Comment: sorry but if I let this Code running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, then I recieve as Output whole source (sadasdasdasdas171212asdadsfsf). How can it happen?

Comment: @beterman undefined behavior means **anything can happen**. You shouldn't do it.

Comment: I dont want to write a new Code. This Code belongs anyone and I am trying to unterstand, how it works

Comment: @beterman it doesn't work. It's wrong code which exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @beterman :  The code you have is incorrect code that has Undefined Behavior.  If you need to copy into a char array, then use `strncpy(dst, src, len)`, but beware the fact that `strncpy` doesn't guarantee to put a NUL terminator on the C-style string.  You have to change _something_.  If you _do_ use `strncpy`, you need to be very careful to get it correct.  More people get it wrong than right when they first start using it.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` does not finish until it's ran out of data in the *source* string (i.e. it hits a null terminator). It's therefore possible to emit *undefined behavour* if your pre-allocated destination string is not large enough.

consider use `strncpy` instead which, in this respect, is safer.

Comment: After you've considered using `strncpy`, forget about it and use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

> Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by
>   destination, **including the terminating null character (and stopping at
>   that point).**
>
> To avoid overflows, **the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the
>   terminating null character)**, and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.